# After updating til MAMP 3.5 mySQL do not work

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp-pro

I've just updated to MAMP 3.5 and now none om my databases works anymore.

My Mac OS is 10.11.3.

When I start up MAMP 3.5 I get this error: Starting mySQL failed 
You can read my log file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ajuAyw2729QjM4dDVyd0djNmc/view

Then I read some blogs (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124563/update-to-3-5-mysql-couldnt-be-started-please-check-the-log-file-for-more-in) with same issue. And they changed innodb_log_file_size to: 
innodb_log_file_size = 50331648

When I do this, then my mySQL starts fine. But none of my Magento or WordPress sites works anymore.

Now I get error i the PHP log like: 
[24-Mar-2016 14:57:23 UTC] WordPress database error Incorrect information in file: './testuni@002dlive/wp_posts.frm' for query SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts

I can find the DBs in my PHPMyAdmin. But also in PHPMyAdmin there happens funny things. I cannot filter for all the DBen anymore, in the "Filter for database..."

I hope someone can help me here? :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per error logs you have upgraded your mysql from below 5.6 version to 5.6 or higher version as before 5.6 version mysql log file default size was 5M but in 5.6 it has been changed to 48M. So you need to follow below steps-

1. remove ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files from your data directory.
2. comment innodb_log_file_size entry in your my.cnf file.
3. Now restart your mysql service.

Note: I am also seeing other mis-configuration in your logs for example you did not set innodb_buffer_pool_size propertly and other variables also, so check and change as per your requirement.

**Update:**

1. take backup of your my.cnf and now your my.cnf file should be like as below-

---

```
[mysqld]

datadir=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
socket=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysqld.pid

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysqld.log
pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysqld.pid

[client]
socket=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysql.sock
```

---

2. Now make sure that mysql service is not running on your server/system. If running then stop kill it.
3. delete ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files if exist at /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql path.
4. Now restart your mysql service.
5. check logs in /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysqld.log file and share if you are getting any error/issue.

Comment: Hi, 
Thank your for responding!

I follow your guide but that did not do it.

What is wrong with my innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Comment: what db engine you are using myisam, innodb or mixed and what error now you are getting...may you share latest error logs after restarting mysql...

Comment: your .cnf is showing that you are using myisam engine?

Comment: Hi - here is a error log from php_error.log: 
[25-Mar-2016 10:38:23 UTC] WordPress database error Incorrect information in file: './testuni@002dlive/wp_posts.frm' for query SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts

Comment: first do as in my post...if you are able to start mysql then we can do other changes as per your requirement....don't start your production/dev work even mysql started till we sort out issue completely.

Comment: Hi. I very happy that you keep helping me.
Aften following your new guide, I get this error when loading a WordPress page:
160325 12:43:50 [ERROR] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Incorrect information in file: './testuni@002dlive/wp_posts.frm'

Comment: First we need to check that mysql service is running or not...so share mysqld.log details if you are getting any error there...

Comment: I ran this command: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force

Still errors.

I add the new log as a answer. Dont know how to to that else :-)

Comment: Zafar, thank you very much for your help!

After following this guide it all works now: http://blog-en.mamp.info/2015/07/how-to-use-mysql-5-6-with-mamp-and-mamp.html